# How to Import data to sql from Excel data table by c#

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

**Problem**

**How to write code import data table to SQL server 2012 .**

**Details**

I have excel sheet name InvoiceData.xlsx have two columns

```
UnitCode    CurrentMeterReading
21544                2900
22152                9000
19822                9200
```

I get success data from excel sheet to datatable as following :

```
public System.Data. DataTable Showdataprint()
        {

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();   
            string str = @"SELECT  [UnitCode],[CurrentMeterReading] FROM  [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
            com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
            OleDbDataAdapter oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            oledbda = new OleDbDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = new DataSet();
            oledbda.Fill(ds,"[Sheet1$]");
            con.Close();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables["[Sheet1$]"];
            return dt;

        }
```

I get successfully data from excel to Datatable
Now I need to Import data from datatable to sql server 2012
TableName : WahInvoice
PK : Serial

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WAHInvoice](
    [Serial] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [Month] [int] NULL,
    [UnitCode] [int] NULL,
    [CurrentReadingDate] [date] NULL,
    [CurrentMeterReading] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WAHInvoice_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Serial] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**I need to know how to Import data from excel to sql .**

suppose i have data on sql in table WahInvoice

with max serial 2000 this meaning data will be as following :

```
Serial  UnitCode          CurrentMeterReading
 2001   21544                2900
 2002   22152                9000
 2003   19822                9200
```

and all values for columns remaining will be null .

**Actually what i write for Import data to sql under import button
Under Import button click i write as following :**

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dt = Showdataprint();
//How to import datatable to sql server 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the SqlBulkCopy Method? If you are, please check below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server